# Increase the number of Recent Files in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to increase the number of files that show up in Intellij's Recents Files window? (View -> Recent Files ⌘E)

Answer (score 6):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Advanced Settings | Maximum number of recent files:

[image: Maximum number of recent files]

Older versions:

File | Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | **Recent files limit**.

[image: recent files]

Comment: Nowadays it moved to a slightly different location File | Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Advanced Settings | IDE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6h9I.png

Answer (score 1):

There is also an IntelliJ plugin named "Recent Projects Extender".

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7684-recent-projects-extender

(I am the author)